# removing files after sshfs

Tags: sshfs

l used the following command  :

```
sshfs  vincet@remote_server:/home/code /home/my_code_remote_server
```

After that if in my laptop l do the following :

```
rm -rf /home/my_code_remote_server
```

Am l going to remove also the directory in the remote server `vincet@remote_server:/home/code` ?

Thank you

Comment: I would think so why not test one file delete!

Comment: If I may ask what are you trying to do, perhaps this would help answer your question due to a better understanding!

Comment: l'm mounting a distant file system

Comment: Yes I know, delete; I would think the essence of mounting such a distant filesystem would be to do whatever one likes on it. remove `/home/my_code_remote_server` should do so remotely. Code dir in remote should be deleted!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. l thought l don't have the privilege of deleting

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen , is there any way to get back the removed vincet@remote_server:/home/code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70340/discussion-between-vincet-and-george-udosen).

Comment: No, just back it up!